# How to remove /Volume from rsync destination path

Tags: bash, rsync

I am trying to backup similar to time machine, many examples on the web are not complete.  I am trying to do relative path -R but the destination includes /Volume and hides it so I cannot see backup until I manually unhide the folder.  I am using -R also so non-existing directory will be created. Destination is to usb flash drive containing sparse bundle.

Source /Volume/Drive/Folder
Destination /Volume/USBBackup

I have tried putting in my filter.txt file:
H /Volumes/*
with and without this /Volume is included and hidden.

rsync -avHAXNR --fileflags --force-change --numeric-ids --protect-args --stats --progress --filter="._$FILTER" --exclude-from="$EXC" --link-dest="/Volume/USBBackup/$PREVDIR" "/Volume/Drive/Folder" "/Volume/USBBackup/name-timestamp/" 2> ~/Desktop/rsync-errors.txt

what gets backed up is /Volume/USBBackup/name-timestamp/Volume/Drive/Folder with Volume hidden.
what I want instead
/Volume/USBBackup/name-timestamp/Drive/Folder
not hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered changing your working directory to /Volume while running that task?

You should be able to do something like:

(cd /Volumes; rsync Drive/Folder)

Or you could:

```sh
OLDPWD=$(pwd)
cd /Volumes
rsync Drive/Folder /Volumes/USBBackup....
cd $OLDPWD
```

Comment: thank you Kyle.  didn't know cd would work on rsync.